# DHCP Server priority

Tags: debian, dhcp, bind

I have a LAN of 4 computers connected through D-Link dir-300 router. This router have own dhcpd and IP adress 192.168.0.1, but i want to use one of computers as dhcp server. I got install bind9 to 192.168.0.100 machine, disable router's own dhcpd and it's work - now other computers requests IP addresses from 192.168.0.100. But if I shut down this computer, network will has no dhcp servers, right? So, can I specify 192.168.0.100 as "primary dhcp server" and router as "fallback dhcp server", which will normally ignores IP requests but works if primary dhcp server is down?

Sorry for my english :\

Comment: DHCP Relays are capable of doing stuff like this (in some but not all cases).  But I think in your setup, you might have trouble doing this.  Unless your DHCP server on the router is capable of knowing if the primary is online and odds are, it will not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redundant DHCP servers are best deployed as active/active with each server offering half of the available scope. The way DHCP works, whichever server responds first will be used by the client.

Comment: Correct for this specific case. However, DHCP failover is more appropriate for anything larger than a home network.